# Pug (Jade) add presence of attribute inline dynamically

Tags: javascript, pug, dhtml

Depending on a variable, the `style` attribute can be present or not.

```
label(for='ff' 
  class='ff1' 
  varFlag != undefined ? eval(style= 'letter-spacing: -5px;') : eval('')
)
```

-- that does not work. And the following code adds empty style, that is not accaptable:

```
label(for='ff' 
  class='ff1' 
  style= varFlag != undefined ? 'letter-spacing: -5px;' : ''
)
```

How can we have an attribute depending on a condition?

Checked similar questios - found nothing relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to have two separate elements for that scenario:

```
if !varFlag
  label(for='ff' class='ff11')
else 
  label(for='ff' class='ff1' style="letter-spacing: -5px")
```

Or if you want to get really fancy, [you could use a `mixin`](https://pugjs.org/language/mixins.html), but that might be more heavy lifting than is needed.

Comment: Thank you! Though I already got a better approach -set false instead if '' https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html#boolean-attributes